# REGEX: Grabbing everything until a specific word

Tags: php, html, regex

ex: `<a><strike>example data in here</strike></a>`

I want everything inside the a tag, to the end

```
/<a>([^<]*)<\/a>/
```

It works when there are no additional tags within the `<a>` tag, but what if there are?

I want to know if you can tell it to grab everything up to `[^</a>]` instead of `[^<]` only.

Doing it with `/<a>(.*)<\/a>/` doesn't work well. Sometimes I get everything in the `<a>` tag and other times I get tons of lines included in that call.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/
```

should work.  The ? makes it lazy, so it grabs as little as possible before matching the `</a>` part.  but using . will mean that it matches everything until it finds `</a>`. If you want to be able to match across lines, you can use the following if with [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/s
```

The "s" at the end puts the regular expression in "single line" mode, which means the . character matches all characters including new lines. See [other useful modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: this will work until you have an <a> inside an <a>:

<a><a></a></a>

and this is identical to the famous parentheses matching regex problem.  there is no solution to this problem with conventional regex.  you're better off with a plain old stack.

Comment: In what messed up version of HTML does an <a> occur within another <a> tag?

Comment: @Kibbee: the messed up version you find scattered all over the place 
on the world wide web ;-)

Comment: However, even if you used a nice HTML Parser like Beautiful Soup, what kind of results could you expect in a situation with nested links?  For bad input the results are undefined.  Does it throw an exception, or does it make a best guess? There is no right output when bad data is fed in.

Comment: great solution.. fine, but use this corrected version instead, to match the possibly new lines too: /<a>([\w\W]*?)<\/a>/

Comment: It is not said that the input comes from the web. I use this regex because the data I feed into it is locally stored and has correct html.

Comment: Right under my nose the whole time on the regexpal.com cheatsheet... (which I refer to religiously) I've been wondering how to do this for quite some time now! Thanks!