# Remove unwanted tags using regular expression

Tags: html, regex

This is my text:

```
301 Roger Complex, Nr. Saint Martin Rd, NY ,380009<br /><a class="popsearchfont" href="javascript:jd_initialize(2, 1, 4);_clickTracker('viewmap','lspg');"><b>View Map</b></a>
```

I want to remove everything after `<br />` so that it looks like as follows using regular expression:

```
301 Roger Complex, Nr. Saint Martin Rd, NY ,380009
```

Comment: Why don't you use simple string processing functions? Get the index of the substring `<br />` and take the substring from `0` to `index`. I'm sure the programming language you are using offers such functions. Regex is not needed at all here.

Comment: Well i have to use regular expression because i am using a scrapper

Comment: How about providing more information about the context?

Comment: @NullUserException well it a kind of desktop client so it extracts the above text and to get the clean text i want to apply a pattern

Comment: I think this is what you're talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147052/regex-grabbing-everything-until-a-specific-word

Comment: Very hard to be helpful without more context. Seriously, consider not using regular expressions. This string manipulation is simple in most (I'd wager all) programming languages. If you insist on a regexp, consider something like ([\s\S]+)\<br /\>

Comment: @murgatroid99 Please do not be kneejerkingly st∞pid. **It is often completely appropriate and indeed optimal to use regexes on HTML.** Consider the following example of one such situation: you are in a text editor and you type the command `100,200s:<br */>::g`. That is completely reasonable, and your kneejerk wisecracking response telling people to write some super-over-engineered monster for a simple text edit is not just unhelpful in the extreme: it is downright harmful.

Comment: @Hunt: You are right that regexes are the natural way to go about this, and some of the given answers below show. Using substring and index is a lot more awkward, which is why regexes exist. Trying to use index and substring to extract the string between the first `foo` and the first `bar` following is a royal pain, hard to read and hard to type, compared to the succinct and clear pattern `foo(.*?)bar`. Your instincts are correct, despite these jokers who all seem to have some insecurity-based hate-affair with regexes. They probably just aren’t very good with them.

Comment: @tchrist You're right, I reacted too quickly to seeing someone ask about html and regex together. I am just used to seeing so many questions in which people want to use regex for parsing html and it's a bad idea. I deleted my other comment.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks. It’s just as bad to not use regexes for jobs they’re good at as it is to use them for jobs they’re bad at. There are times when HTML falls into the first of those groups, and times when it falls into the second. No unthinking Pavlovian response will ever give an invariably appropriate answer, but that’s the dominant response here on SO. It sends too many people down convoluted paths they should not trod. All else being equal, the simplest and shortest solution wins, whether it uses regexes or not.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done in Vim using a simple sed command.

```
:%s/<br \/>.*$//g
```

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you want to either remove everything matching this:

```
/<br \/>.*$/i
```

Or keep everything matching this:

```
/^.*?(?=<br \/>)/i
```

Either one of these should work; just pick whatever you like better. Note that something like `<   br    >` is still valid HTML, so if you're not sure what the actual input will be like, you may want to consider changing `<br \/>` to `<\s*br\s*\/?>` or even `<\s*br\b[^>]*>`.