# PHP Regex of Anchor with Class to get Inner Text

Tags: php, regex

```
<a href="/search?hl=en&amp;pwst=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=RCPqTqkHycryA_bK_f0J&amp;ved=0CCUQvwUoAQ&amp;q=psychology&amp;spell=1" class=spell><b><i>psychology</i></b></a>
```

Hi, I'm looking to create a regex which matches this anchor and returns the inner text of it.

This is what I've been trying as a regex but without success.

```
'/<a[^>]+class=\"spell\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/isU'
```

It's probably something really silly. Thanks.

---

Problem was missing quotes surrounding the class. Not proper html markup but I neglected to notice so I just changed my regex to have quotes as optional.

Final regex:

```
'/<a[^>]+class=\"?spell\"?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/is'
```

Comment: Please be more specific. "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: You should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147052/regex-grabbing-everything-until-a-specific-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex looks OK, although you don't need to escape the quotes. Perhaps PHP doesn't like it if you use unnecessary escapes, although I doubt it. The problem is more likely the way you're using the regex. Did you access group number 1?

```
if (preg_match('%<a[^>]+class="spell"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>%', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. It seems the regex isn't my problem but where I am grabbing my html from.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be the combination of `(.*?)` and `/isU` modifier. That `U` alters the meaning of `?` making your match group `(.*)` greedy actually. Then you will match parts beyond the `<\/a>` end marker, until it encounters another.

If you remove the `/U` it works as expected. With your given input text, at least.

Comment: Good point, although of course his version works in his sample string, too.

Comment: Just a guess of course. Otherwise it seemed to match as expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are two options to fix your expression:**

For starters, you can simplify your expression to:

```
class=\"spell\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

This captures

```
<b><i>psychology</i></b>
```

in Group 1. I assume this is what you want to achieve.

Then, if you want to capture "psychology" without the bold and italic tags, you can use:

```
class=\"spell\"[^>]*>\s*<(\w+)>?\s*<(\w+)>?\s*(.*?)<\/\2>\s*<\/\1>\s*<\/a>
```

This captures "psychology" in group 3. 
In group 1, you will find the first optional tag, whether it be "b", "strong" or nothing.
In group 2, you will find the second optional tag, which was "i" in your example.

The multiple instances of \s* allow for optional space between the tags.

Is this what you were looking for?